# sql query for table names with pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, io

I'm trying to read the Table names from a database into a list using Pandas.read_sql. 
I have tried different SQL queries found online:

```
     cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=' + str(self.file_selected)+';Uid=Admin;Pwd=; ')
  #  sql = "SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLES" # tried this - also an error

  sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name.MDB'"
    self.TableNames = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
    cnxn.close()
```

but I get an error that it can not find the file database_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

what should I use for the sql query?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing as `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in `MS Access`...

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, you can retrieve metadata on a database using its system table, *MSysObjects*. Below is a DML call to retrieve all table names:

```sql
SELECT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MsysObjects 
WHERE ((MSysObjects.Type)=1)
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;
```

However, by default this will not work with external ODBC calls such as you do in Python as permission is not allowed. To resolve, consider two routes:

**Grant Permission** *(for Admin user)*

Inside the MSAccess.exe GUI, open database and run VBA subroutine (in standalone module) which only needs to be run once:

```vb
Public Sub GrantMSysPermission()
   Dim strSQL As String
   strSQL = "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"

   CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
End Sub
```

Once done run above query in pandas `read_sql` call.

**Saved Table**

Inside MS Access.exe GUI program, run below make-table query:

```sql
SELECT MSysObjects.Name
INTO DBTables
FROM MsysObjects 
WHERE ((MSysObjects.Type)=1)
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;
```

Then in Python pandas, refer to new table:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}};DBQ=' + \
                      '{};Uid=Admin;Pwd=;'.format(str(self.file_selected)))

sql = "SELECT * DBTables"
self.TableNames = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```